# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out when sent message

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, web-services, restful-architecture

```
 Oct 05, 2015 11:16:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
 invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
 [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] in context with path [/FunkyApp] threw
 exception org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out    at
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at
 java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at
 java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at
 java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
 java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)   at
 java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)   at
 sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)    at
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)    at
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)    at
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init(HttpClient.java:211)     at
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)   at
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)   at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at
 obl.funkey.service.FunkeyServiceImpl.getLanguageInfo(FunkeyServiceImpl.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at
 org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
    ... 26 more
```

I develop Restful web service then there are use maven for project build. I try to connect java code

```
URL url = new URL(requestURL);
StringReader  requestReader = new StringReader(calloutRequest);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" );
connection.connect();
Writer connWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
int c;
StringBuffer ResponserStr =new StringBuffer();

while ( (c = requestReader.read()) != -1 ){  
    connWriter.write( (char)c );
}

connWriter.flush();
connection.getOutputStream().close();
java.lang.Object response2 = connection.getContent();
Reader connReader = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) response2 );

while ( (c = connReader.read()) != -1 ){
    ResponserStr .append(""+(char)c);
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

How I solve that kind error when I develop my Restful web service?

Comment: Can you check connection.getResponseCode() after connect() method? If you did not debug after that line , I suspect 1) Firewall setting in your network (not allowing to connect that port) Or some other network related configuration issues 2) your server is may be too busy (so many requests so that it cannot handle current request.

Comment: I don't know debug in server. using only connection start ./startup.sh in tomcat server.

Comment: I said to add a debug statement with connection.getResponseCode() and check tomcat logs. But as per the stack trace, it seems that it failed in connect itself . i.e some thing to do with firewall/network connection unless your server is too busy